# How to add "?" in string while submitting form with js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, uri

I write a form submit thread with the attr method:

```js
var href = a.attr('href');
if(href =='') return;
if(href.startsWith('http') || href.startsWith('//:')){
  a.attr('href',href.trim());
  if(href.indexOf(location.hostname) > -1){
    return;
  }
  if(href.indexOf('<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>') > -1){
    return;
  }

  a.attr('href','go.htm?uri='+href);
  a.attr('rel','nofollow');
}
```

However, it returns the URL without ?, for example, I want to return https://example.abc.com/?ref=abc, the return result will be https://example.abc.com/ref=abc without "?" the question mark.

I'm struggling with solving this and I appreciate any helpful tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function string. Split your URL with "?" and take first element.

```
var yourRequiredLink = href.replace("?", '')
```

Comment: or is it good to split this into a function, and use the function in the attr method?

Comment: Yes you can do that as well. It depends on size of project and standard you want to follow. If it's just for learning/small project then you can getaway without function.

Comment: href.split('?') will return an array of string split by "?". By example ['https://example.abc.com/', 'ref=abc'] so you will have parts of URL without "?".

Comment: and I think I have a better solution for your problem use `href.replace("?", '')` this should do the trick @LLLgoyour